# How would I get the right output for my methods?

Tags: java, arrays

I want do display the Quizzes,Labs, Lab attendance, Midterms like like this-
Quizzes: 66%
Labs: 88%
Lab attendance: 81%
Midterms: 91%
Final: Not applicable
Overall Average: 85%.
But I'm getting

output:

```
66.0
88.0
81.0
91.0
```

How would I get the right output for what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

public class FindGrade {
    public static final int NUM_SCORE_TYPES = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        int[] quizArray = null;
        int[] labArray = null;
        int[] attendance = null;
        int[] midterms = null;
        int quizgrade = 0;
        int labgrade = 0;
        int attendance_1 = 0;
        int midterms_1 = 0;
        String name;


        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // each iteration is for single exam type (ie: Quizzes is the 1st one)
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SCORE_TYPES; i++) {

            name = scan.next();
            int numScores = scan.nextInt();
            int maxGrade = scan.nextInt();

            if (name.equals("Quizzes")) {
                quizArray = new int[numScores];
                readScores(quizArray, numScores, scan,maxGrade);


            } else if (name.equals("Labs")) {
                labArray = new int[numScores];
                readScores(labArray, numScores, scan,maxGrade);

            } else if (name.equals("Lab_attendance")) {
                attendance = new int[numScores];
                readScores(attendance, numScores, scan,maxGrade);

            } else if (name.equals("Midterms")) {
                midterms = new int[numScores];
                readScores(midterms, numScores, scan,maxGrade);

            }

        }

    }


    public static void readScores(int[] scoreArray, int numScores, Scanner scan, int maxGrade) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++) {
            scoreArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(average(scoreArray, numScores, maxGrade));
    }

    public static int normalize(int[] scoreArray, int maxGrade) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
            total += scoreArray[i];
        }
        int percent = Math.round(total * 100 / maxGrade);
        return percent;
    }

    public static double average(double[] scoreArray, int numScores,int maxGrade) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
            sum += scoreArray[i];
        }
        double average = Math.round((sum / numScores)*100/maxGrade);

        return average;
```

}

input file:

```
Quizzes 8 10
5 8 9 10 4 0 10 7
Labs 6 100
95 90 100 87 63 92
Lab_attendance 16 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
Midterms 2 100
87 94
Final 0 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your modified code & expected o/p :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FindGrade {
public static final int NUM_SCORE_TYPES = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = null;
    String quizzes=  "Quizzes";
    String labs= "Labs";
    String lab_attendance=  "Lab_attendance";
    String midterm=  "Midterms";
    int[] quizArray = null;
    int[] labArray = null;
    int[] attendance = null;
    int[] midterms = null;
    int quizgrade = 0;
    int labgrade = 0;
    int attendance_1 = 0;
    int midterms_1 = 0;
    String name;


    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new File("C://Users//Desktop//input.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    // each iteration is for single exam type (ie: Quizzes is the 1st one)
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SCORE_TYPES; i++) {

        name = scan.next();
        int numScores = scan.nextInt();
        int maxGrade = scan.nextInt();

        if (name.equals("Quizzes")) {
            quizArray = new int[numScores];
            readScores(quizArray, numScores, scan,maxGrade, quizzes);


        } else if (name.equals("Labs")) {
            labArray = new int[numScores];
            readScores(labArray, numScores, scan,maxGrade, labs);

        } else if (name.equals("Lab_attendance")) {
            attendance = new int[numScores];
            readScores(attendance, numScores, scan,maxGrade,lab_attendance );

        } else if (name.equals("Midterms")) {
            midterms = new int[numScores];
            readScores(midterms, numScores, scan,maxGrade, midterm);

        }

    }

}


public static void readScores(int[] scoreArray, int numScores, Scanner scan, int maxGrade, String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++) {
        scoreArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    average(scoreArray, numScores, maxGrade, name);
}

public static int normalize(int[] scoreArray, int maxGrade) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
        total += scoreArray[i];
    }
    int percent = Math.round(total * 100 / maxGrade);
    return percent;
}

public static double average(int[] scoreArray, int numScores,int maxGrade, String name) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
        sum += scoreArray[i];
    }
    double average = Math.round((sum / numScores)*100/maxGrade);

    System.out.println( name + ":" + average+" %");

    return average;
}
}
```

**And Result is :**

```
Quizzes:66.0 %
Labs:88.0 %
Lab_attendance:81.0 %
Midterms:91.0 %**
```

Comment: If I wanted to include the overall average would I approach it the same way I did for the average method

Comment: @user124557--Okay you mean to take final average of the result, yes you can use your avreage method like wise or create a separate method for calculating final avg and printing. Hope it helped !

Comment: Dear @user124557 if it worked or helped you may appreciate by accepting as an answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the name to Average and print the name and the score.
Look below the fixed code with a suggestion, it gives the input you are looking for.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FindGrade {
public static final int NUM_SCORE_TYPES = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = null;
    int[] quizArray = null;
    int[] labArray = null;
    int[] attendance = null;
    int[] midterms = null;
    int quizgrade = 0;
    int labgrade = 0;
    int attendance_1 = 0;
    int midterms_1 = 0;
    String name;


    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new File("c:\\temp\\input.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    // each iteration is for single exam type (ie: Quizzes is the 1st one)
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SCORE_TYPES; i++) {

        name = scan.next();
        int numScores = scan.nextInt();
        int maxGrade = scan.nextInt();

        if (name.equals("Quizzes")) {
            quizArray = new int[numScores];
            readScores(quizArray, numScores, scan,maxGrade, "Quizzes");


        } else if (name.equals("Labs")) {
            labArray = new int[numScores];
            readScores(labArray, numScores, scan,maxGrade, "Labs");

        } else if (name.equals("Lab_attendance")) {
            attendance = new int[numScores];
            readScores(attendance, numScores, scan,maxGrade, "Lab_attendance");

        } else if (name.equals("Midterms")) {
            midterms = new int[numScores];
            readScores(midterms, numScores, scan,maxGrade, "Midterms");

        }

    }

}


public static void readScores(int[] scoreArray, int numScores, Scanner scan, int maxGrade, String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++) {
        scoreArray[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    average(scoreArray, numScores, maxGrade, name);
}

public static int normalize(int[] scoreArray, int maxGrade) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
        total += scoreArray[i];
    }
    int percent = Math.round(total * 100 / maxGrade);
    return percent;
}

public static double average(int[] scoreArray, int numScores,int maxGrade, String name) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
        sum += scoreArray[i];
    }
    double average = Math.round((sum / numScores)*100/maxGrade);

    System.out.println( name + ":" + average);

    return average;
}
}
```

And then expected output when running it:

```
Quizzes:66.0
Labs:88.0
Lab_attendance:81.0
Midterms:91.0
```

Answer (score -2):

You didn't actually post any code where you're printing *anything*, but what you want is probably [`System.out.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Comment: I forgot to add the s.o.p. I added it to the original code.

Comment: @user124557 No idea why someone downvoted my correct answer; its exactly what you need.